# Conditional Probability of Good vs Bad Drivers

Tags: probability, bayesian

I have a problem I'm working on that I'm not quite getting. The problem starts as such:

Suppose that there are two types of drivers: good drivers and bad drivers. Let G be the event that a particular man is a good driver, A be the event that he gets into a car accident next year, and B be the event that he gets into a car accident the following year. Let P(G) = g and P(A|G) = P(B|G) = p1,P(A|G^c) = P(B|G^c) = p2, with p1 < p2. **Suppose that given the information of whether or not the man is a good driver, A and B are independent.**  (for simplicity and to avoid being morbid, assume that the accidents being considered are minor and wouldn’t make the man unable to drive).

(a) Explain intuitively whether or not A and B are independent.

(b) Find P(G|A^c)

(c) Find P(B|A^c)

I am looking for hints on how to start or think about this problem, as I'm quite stuck at the moment. My work is as follows thus far:

A) If a driver gets into a car crash in the first year (meaning event A occurs, this means that it is more likely that the driver is a bad driver. Hence, it is more likely that event B occurs, meaning they are not independent.

B) I immediately expand our desired probability as follows:

$$P(G|A^c) = \frac{P(A^c|G)P(G)}{P(A^c)}$$

Using LOTP, we can expand the denominator as such:

$$P(G|A^c) = \frac{P(A^c|G)*g}{P(A^c|G)*g + P(A^c|G^c)P(G^c)}$$

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track, but turned left at Albuquerque.

You just want: $\def\P{\mathop{\mathsf P}}~\P(G\mid A^\complement)~{=\dfrac{\P(A^\complement\mid G)\P(G)}{\P(A^\complement)}\\ = \dfrac{\P(A^\complement\mid G)\P(G)}{\P(A^\complement\mid G)\P(G)+\P(A^\complement\mid G^\complement)\P(G^\complement)}}$

And you can finish it from here.

---

PS: Your argument on the interdependence of $A,B$ was good.

Comment: Thanks, I also expanded the denominator using LOTP. Another question, should be noting that P(A^c|G) is the complement of P(A|G)?

Comment: @Workhorse Indeed $\P(A^\complement\mid G)=1-\P(A\mid G)$